# multiple nested callback functions before parent's callback in javascript

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Im using expressjs and mysql package.
I have a user table, each user could have many skills, projects, certifications stored in different tables. How can I get all of these data into a single user object.

```
getUserDataById(req.params.id, function (user) {
  if (user) {
    res.send(user);     
  }
}
var getUserDataById = function (id, callback) {
  connection.query(userSql, id, function (err, rows) {
    if (rows[0]) {
      user = new User(rows[0]); //parse row data to user obj  
      // The main problem 
      //get skills and projects.... and asign to user obj
      parseArrayData(skillSql, user.id, Skill, function (skills) {
          user.skills = skills;
        }
      );
      parseArrayData(projectSql, user.id, Project, function (project) {
          user.projects = projects;
        }
      );
      // is here
      callback(user);
    }
  });
}
var parseArrayData = function (query, id, Obj, callback) {
  connection.pool.query(query, id, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log('rows',rows);
      var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new Obj(rows[i]); // map obj's attributes with fields
      };
      callback(rows);
    }
  });       
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have these different tables with names (assume): `users`, `skills`, `projects`, `certifications`;

function to get result from db for query;

```
function executeQuery(tablename, userId, callback) {
  var sql = 'select * from ' + tablename + ' where id = ' + userId;
  connection.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) { callback(err, null); }
    else { callback(null, rows); }
  })
}
```

Function that will fetch all results for user id and return json object;

```
 var getUserDataById = function (userId, callback) {
    executeQuery('users', userId, function(users) {
       executeQuery('projects', userId, function(projects) {
          executeQuery('skills', userId, function(skills) {
             executeQuery('certifications', userId, function(certifications) {
                var result = { // format you result.
                   id: userId,
                   users: users,
                   projects: projects,
                   skills: skills,
                   certifications: certifications
                };
                callback(result);
             }); 
          });
       });
    });
    callback(null);
 });
```

Usage:

```
getUserDataById(req.params.id, function (user) {
  if (user) {
    res.send(user);     
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @narainsagar. This could help me solve my problem. I've found `promise` could help in this situation. I will try to solve it that way

Comment: I used callbacks because you didn't mention es6 or used promises in code. your code contained callbacks so i used callbacks too

Comment: can you give me an advice to use `promise`. I hardly get how to implement it in node from this [Q document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)

Comment: I don't have much idea but this might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: And Also I think you can not run es6 (promises) directly via node so may be you need to setup & use [babel](http://babeljs.io/)